# How to call method in symbol without assigning to variable

Tags: ecmascript-6

The following works fine by assigning Symbol to sayHello.

```
var sayHello = Symbol('method');
const bar = {
  [sayHello] () { 
    console.log('hello')  
  }
};

bar[sayHello]();
```

How to trigger the method inside Symbol if as follow

```
const bar3 = {
  [Symbol('method')] () { 
    console.log('hello')  
  }
};
```

Comment: You need the symbol twice, once to define the method and once to call it. What's wrong with the natural solution of storing it in a constant for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
const sym = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bar3)[0];
bar3[sym]();
```

See [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) documentation.

Comment: is there anyway to trigger it within a single line instead of assigning to a const?

Comment: Of course, just inline the definition `bar3[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bar3)[0]]();` Why didn't you try this yourself?

Comment: My mistake, been trying in the wrong direction (thinking). Was doing smth like `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bar3)[0]()`. Thanks Alexey.